# Windows 10 Black screen after boot logo

Tags: windows, boot, black-screen-of-death

So i have been running into this issue with windows 10 on my laptop. After the boot logo it just becomes a black screen. But after I put it to sleep by closing the lid and then waking it back up it works. I have no idea why this happens and can't find anything like this on the internet.

I tried:
*Reinstalling windows 10

*Updating all my drivers

*Turning off​ fast boot (which made it even worse)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like a DRIVER_POWER STATE FAILURE, it could be one of the drivers I not configured properly or is not compatible. Have you checked if all installed drivers are manufacturer (vendor supplied)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a DRIVER_POWER STATE FAILURE, it could be one of the drivers  not configured properly or is not compatible. Have you checked if you have any other third party drivers installed? Check their compatibility with Windows 10

Also;

- Check in Event viewer possible information on error encountered during sleep on booting processes
- Check powercfg parameters or even possible events that trigger wake processes in your machine: `powercfg /systemsleepdiagnostics` or `powercfg / lastwake`try to see which processes are implicated in this behaviour.

Had a problem with black screen after updating to windows 10, but I had to update **graphics driver through windows update** since windows itself determines the most suitable driver for best compatibility.

Comment: I found out I actually needed a BIOS update to support windows 10.

Comment: Hadn't updated it since 2011 :$

Comment: @user703875, thanks, I am glad you managed to solve the problem. Cheers